# Error: Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos

Tags: heroku

I'm try to run a python manage.py [commands] but give me this error message every time 
"""
 »   Error: Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos.
 »
 »   Error ID: cannot_run_above_limit
 »   See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size#default-scaling-limits for more information.
"""

Comment: Pls show config files (Proc file, Docker?)

Comment: (Procfile:) web: gunicorn disquaire_project.wgsi